# Why is my answer to calculate the expected collisions of hashing wrong?

Tags: algorithm, hash, probability

The problem is:

> Suppose we use a hash function  to hash  distinct balls into  distinct bins. Assuming simple uniform hashing, what is the expected number of collisions?

And I came up with an answer: The expected number of collisions is `m*C^{2}_{n/m}`, while `m` is the number of slots and `n/m` is the expected number of keys in a slot. (Assuming that `n/m` is an integer)

Then my answer is: `m*C^{2}_{n/m} = n(n-m)/2m` while most solutions to CLRS show that the answer is `n(n-1)/2m`.

I don't know why I'm wrong. Could someone tell me please?

Comment: Your answer results in zero when `n==m`, and a negative number when `0 < n < m`. The other answer predicts 0 collisions for `n==0` or `n==1`, and an expected `1/m` collisions for `n==2`. So at least that's a good start.

Comment: Ah, I finally understand your calculation. The problem is the assumption that `n/m` is an integer. That only allows `n=0, m, 2m, ...` When `n=0`, the prediction is 0 collisions, which is correct. When `n==m`, the prediction is 1 ball in each bin, so 0 collisions. That is not correct, since there may be multiple balls in some bins, and none in others. For `n==2m`, the predication is `2m(2m-m)/2m` which is `m` collisions. That's based on assuming that there are exactly 2 balls in each bin, which is not true. Your equation only works for very large values of `n`, so that `n/m` is about right.